# ASP.NET Currency regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, webforms

The currency required format looks like

```
1,100,258
100,258
23,258
3,258
```

Or all integers like 
`123456` or `2421323` and so on.

I type below in `ValidationExpression`

```
(^[0-9]{1,3}(,\d{3})*) | (^[0-9][0-9]*)
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have `ignore pattern whitespace` on? If not, remove the two spaces on each side of the pipe.

Since you're trying to match either, you should stick a marker `$` at the end of the string, like so

Also what is the point of `^[0-9][0-9]*`, when you can use `^[0-9]+`?

```
^([0-9]{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|[0-9]+)$
```

or

```
^(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)$
```

Explanation:

```
 ^                     # Anchors to the beginning to the string.
 (                     # Opens CG1
     \d{1,3}           # Token: \d (digit)
     (?:               # Opens NCG
         ,             # Literal ,
         \d{3}         # Token: \d (digit)
                         # Repeats 3 times.
     )*                # Closes NCG
                         # * repeats zero or more times
 |                     # Alternation (CG1)
     \d+               # Token: \d (digit)
                         # + repeats one or more times
 )                     # Closes CG1
 $                     # Anchors to the end to the string.
```

Comment: Glad it worked, and thanks. You can also upvote answers :). You can upvote as many answers as you like, while you can only accept one as "The Answer", of course. @CodaChang